# How to upload a package to Launchpad using quickly

Tags: launchpad

I've successfully reached the point, where I was able to persuade quickly to upload my testing package to Launchpad with almost no error. However, I've got the following problem:

```
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
.........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.......pushing to launchpad
.............................Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made Fri Jun 22 21:28:42 2012 CEST using RSA key ID 03790459
gpg: Good signature from "Zubozrout <zubozrout@gmail.com>"
Good signature on ../omega_12.06.6_source.changes.
Checking signature on .dsc
gpg: Signature made Fri Jun 22 21:28:42 2012 CEST using RSA key ID 03790459
gpg: Good signature from "Zubozrout <zubozrout@gmail.com>"
Good signature on ../omega_12.06.6.dsc.
Uploading to ppa (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
  Uploading omega_12.06.6.dsc: done.
  Uploading omega_12.06.6.tar.gz: done.  
  Uploading omega_12.06.6_source.changes: done.
Successfully uploaded packages.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/release.py", line 287, in <module>
    release_version), changelog)
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/launchpad_helper.py", line 57, in push_tarball_to_launchpad
    release = create_release(project, version)
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/internal/launchpad_helper.py", line 44, in create_release
    date_targeted=release_date)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 573, in __call__
    url, in_representation, http_method, extra_headers=extra_headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 281, in _request
    raise error
lazr.restfulclient.errors.Unauthorized: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Response headers:
---
-content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 65
content-type: text/plain
date: Fri, 22 Jun 2012 19:28:46 GMT
server: zope.server.http (HTTP)
status: 401
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000
vary: Accept,Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 api.launchpad.net
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-lazr-notifications: []
x-powered-by: Zope (www.zope.org), Python (www.python.org)
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
---
Response body:
---
(<ProductSeries at 0x14030190>, 'newMilestone', 'launchpad.Edit')
---

ERROR: release command failed
Aborting
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, so even though there is an error after upload, my packages seem to be available now in Launchpad. So - it works and does not depend on the error.

Comment: If this is working you should add your comment as an answer to your own question and accept it. That will get this off the unanswered list and so help future users identify your question as one to which there is a satisfactory answer. Answering your own questions is more than okay, and is in fact [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) because, if it's a good question and a correct answer, it will help people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works even though the error is displayed.